# Simple apps android to learn / build for beginner (dont too complex)

Tags: android

before.. I try to browse some keyword to learn simple apps android for beginner such as Todo Apps, Note, Calculator, etc. after that I don't know what I can find more about simple apps to rich my skill, I just find more complex apps and little bit need long time and hard to understand it.

Can you tell me a summary maybe some apps android recommendation to learn or build for beginner ? If you have example or a link would be good

If you have some tips to easy and quick learn just share below please.

Thank you so much before for your leisure time to answer mine :)

Comment: May I suggest you Android documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

Comment: Also look into https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837 , it's a free course built by Google for beginners.

Comment: can you mention the apps name like maps, notebook, etc ?
So i can browse it later

Comment: you should start with an offline application first. try creating an offline bible app, where you will use sqlite database, and create a new design by refferring all the other bible app.

Answer (score 1):

Think about write your own Music Player, Chat app using Firebase, Calendar, Dialer, Message, you can learn more about service, broardcast receiver, notification,... on Android :) Everything available on Google :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create basic & simple apps by using free apies.
you can learn basics from the demo projects.